# Problem in executing query using ormlite in android

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

I'm using the program found on [this programming blog](http://www.b-fil.com/blog/2011/01/20/android-repository-ormlite-existing-sqlite-db/#c25) for using pre-populated sqlite table.  I am trying to insert any row in the table but it is giving always SQLException:

```
Problems executing Android query: SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `username`='Shadow'
```

This is the method where I'm getting this error:

```
public User getByUsername(String username) {        
    try {
        QueryBuilder<User, String> qb = userDao.queryBuilder(); 
        qb.where().eq("username", username);    
        PreparedQuery<User> pq = qb.prepare();
        return userDao.queryForFirst(pq);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Looking for help...

Comment: Can you please post the entire exception?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without more information about the specific error you are getting (please add the full exception to your question), we can't really help you @deepak

I will say that your code looks well formed and appropriate.  I like to define the fields that I use in queries like the following:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "users")
public class User @{
    public static final String USERNAME_FIELD_NAME = "username"; 

    ...
    @DatabaseField(columnName = USERNAME_FIELD_NAME)
    private String userName;
    ...
```

Then your code can be something like the following.  This solves problems with queries and database schemas not matching:

```
qb.where().eq(User.USERNAME_FIELD_NAME, username);
```

If you post your exception, I'll edit my answer with more help.

Comment: Thanks for your response,But this is also occuring when i'm executing the daoObject.queryForAll() method and it is giving the same SQLEXCEPTION Problems executing Android query: SELECT * FROM `user` .

Comment: Can you please post the *entire exception* to your question?

Comment: I debug my source code and i found that query method of StatementExecuter class is throwing SQL Exception but i'm not gettind what is the reason behind it.

Comment: Thanks dude with your approach i debug again and found that the error was due to wrong column name.Any way your idea for posting entire exception give a clue to me and i attached the source code of the ormlite and found the solution thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget to write the default constructor of your Entity Class. In my case i forgot to write the constructor and was getting the same exception.

```
public User(){

}
```